# Missing feature labels stored with QGIS auxiliary storage

Tags: qgis, labeling

Using QGIS 3.x, I appended new features to a PostGIS feature table for which I had previously generated and modified labels stored in auxiliary storage. No labels are placed for these new features even when the label editor is active.

I don't want to delete existing labels because they are where I want them. What is an efficient way to place labels for these new features, and subsequently to be able to edit them?